# strugelling with building a bundle app using electron-react-vite with loadFiles not webserver

Tags: reactjs, electron, vite, electron-builder, electron-react-boilerplate

I am trying to learn something new here. I am working on client app which uses Electron + react.

I used this github repo to start my project https://github.com/electron-vite/electron-vite-react

And since i am not ready yet to learn typescript, I added //@ts-nocheck to most of my .tsx files in order to avoid  ts warnings/errors till i become ready to learn TS.

My problem that I can not bundle my app to share with others.

in package.json :-

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build && electron-builder",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "pree2e": "vite build --mode=test",
    "e2e": "playwright test"
  },
```

in my first landing electron window = *electron/windows/win_landing.ts*
I am loading the `index.html`

```
mainWindow.loadURL(indexHtml, { hash: arg })
```

Then i run `npm run build`

whenever i try to launch the bundeled app which generated under dist/, i get

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <title>Orion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.tsx" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This error never show up when i use `mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:5173/app/landing')` in my win_landing.

I tried to change `<script type="module" src="./src/main.tsx" ></script>` in my index.html file to main.js, I receive this error

`caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react/jsx-runtime". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I tried to change the name of my main react js script to index.js instead of index.tsx,
also tried to change to .mjs.

Also tried to add         `mimeTypes: { 'ts': 'application/javascript', 'tsx': 'application/javascript', }`
to vite.config.ts

If you could help me to figure out what i am missing to build my app correctly i will be grateful.

Here is my github repo if you want to give a deeper look

[GITHUB](https://github.com/meddany/orion-ui-client)

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem!